# What would be the best (simplest?) practice for redirecting power and data lines based on the presence of a host usb connection or it's absence?

Tags: mosfet, batteries, switches, bluetooth, keyboard

Basically I'm trying to use a Handheld Scientific BT-500 bluetooth keyboard adapter to make an existing keyboard wireless. The way the module works is if power is supplied (but no data) it activates bluetooth and connects with the host computer as a wireless HID. When the module is supplied with power AND data, it acts as an intermediary and passes data down the line (deactivating  bluetooth). The problem is that as the module stands in between the keyboard PCB and the host computer, it appears as a different HID device and thus I lose access to software features I'm keen to take advantage of (at least when the host usb is plugged in).

For this reason, I'd like to set this up that in scenarios where the host device is unplugged and the circuit is running on the internal battery, the module is supplied power and data/power lines to the keyboard pcb are active. When a host usb connection is established, I'd like power and data to bypass the module entirely. I've scribbled the two scenarios down below:

[image: Scenarios]

If it's not completely clear I'm a total neophyte so apologies for all the conventions I'm certainly violating with my scribbles here. I'd really appreciate any help understanding how I would wire this scenario and what components I might use? My instinct would be that something like an Arduino would be totally overkill for this scenario. Could I perhaps use a few logic level mosfets to detect 5v coming in from the usb breakout board and then redirecting power and data that way? If so I'd greatly appreciate an illustration/explanation of where I would position these (as if I was a total moron).